# How to access vue instance data in runtime

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

my question is pretty simple, i want to assign data in run time and get them again in vue instance

```
 data() {
    return {
      panels:[],
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.fetchPanels();
    //console.log(this) , i can find panels already assigned in this instance
    //console.log(this.panels) , it gives me zero array
  },
  methods: {

    fetchPanels() {
        this.$http
        .get(Shared.siteUrl+"/api/" + this.category_title + "/panels")
        .then(function(response) {
          this.panels = response.body.data;
        });
    },
```

Comment: use arrow function in `.then()` statement: `.then(r => this.panels = r.body.data)`

Comment: i used it, it gives same problem

Comment: Your `console.log` in `created()` will run before your http request assigns to `panels`

Comment: this is good explanation,probably vue-resource using async requests . 
but how can i make it wait untill it is assigned

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use async/await (and I agree you should), you should do so for the http call as well. `await somefunc().then()` feels like bad mixing of styles. This has the advantage of also being shorter.

```js
data() {
  return {
    panels:[],
  };
},
async created() {
  await this.fetchPanels();

  console.log(this.panels);
},
methods: {
  async fetchPanels() {
    const response = await this.$http.get(Shared.siteUrl + "/api/" + this.category_title + "/panels")

    this.panels = response.body.data;
  },
```

Keep in mind that the Vue lifecycle does not wait on your async lifecycle hooks. This won't be a problem in this example, but it's definitely good to keep in mind. I.e., if you added

```
mounted() {
  console.log(this.panels);
},
```

it would come up empty, because the async tasks in `created()` will now happen after `mounted()`

Answer (score 0):

Your `console.log(this.panels)` will be called before the async request.
Also, Use arrow function instead.

```
data() {
    return {
      panels:[],
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.fetchPanels();
    //console.log(this) , i can find panels already assigned in this instance
    //console.log(this.panels) , don't use this here
  },
  methods: {

    fetchPanels() {
        this.$http
        .get(Shared.siteUrl+"/api/" + this.category_title + "/panels")
        .then((response) => {
          this.panels = response.body.data;
          console.log(this.panels);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As developers suggested that, vue-resouce uses promise async tasks and to wait untill it gives its data

```
data() {
    return {
      panels:[],
    };
  },
  async created() {
    await this.fetchPanels();
    console.log(this.panels)
  },
  methods: {

    fetchPanels:async function() {
        await this.$http
        .get(Shared.siteUrl+"/api/" + this.category_title + "/panels")
        .then((response) => {
          this.panels = response.body.data;
        });
    }
```